# Finding the parameter a

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The ratio of the roots of the equation $x^2 +ax + a+2=0$ is $2$
Find the values of parameter $a$.
          I don't understand what the question means .

Comment: Do you know what a root of an equation is?  Do you know what a ratio of two numbers is?  *Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the roots are $\alpha~\&~\beta$ then

$$\alpha +\beta=-a~......(1)$$

and$$\alpha \beta=a+2~.....(2)$$

In question it is given that ratio is 2 so $\displaystyle\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=2 \implies \alpha=2\beta$ putting above we have from equation (1),

$\displaystyle\beta=\frac{-a}{3}~\&~\alpha = \frac{-2a}{3}$

Now from equation (2) we have,
$$\frac{-a}{3}\cdot\frac{-2a}{3}=a+2$$
$$\implies 2a^2-9a-18=0$$
from here you can find the value of a

Comment: $a=\displaystyle \frac{9\pm\sqrt{9^2-4\cdot 2\cdot (-18)}}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$a$ is a number we don't know. What about quadratic equations such that one of the roots is twice the other one, just observe a few examples:
\begin{align*}
x^2-3 x +2&=0;\quad\text{ their roots are }\;1\text{ and }2;\;\text{ also }\;\; x^2-3 x+2=x^2-3\cdot 1 x+2\cdot 1^2\\
x^2-6 x+8&=0;\quad\text{ their roots are }\;2\text{ and }4;\;\text{ also }\;\; x^2-6 x+8=x^2-3\cdot 2 x+2\cdot 2^2\\
x^2+12 x+32&=0;\quad\text{ their roots are }\;-4\text{ and }-8;\;\text{ also }\;\; x^2+12x+32=x^2-3(-4)x+2\cdot(-4)^2\\
\end{align*}
Can you note any pattern?